# C: Catch empty Input and print command prompt

Tags: c, event-handling, fgets

Sorry for the bad title, but i didn't know a better one!

Target: I'm trying to make an command handler. So I'm printing out via `printf("cmd: ")` and listing on stdin via `fgets()`. If theres an Input I'm check on commands via `if .. else if`. So my Problem now: If there is no input on stdin it should repeat the function and print cmd!

```
int cmd_handler()
{
  printf("cmd: ");
  char command[LINE_MAX];
  fgets(command, LINE_MAX, stdin);
  if(command != NULL)
  {
   if(strcmp(command, "xyz"))
   {
    xyz();
   }
  }
return 0;
}
```

I really don't know how i can arrange that. simple call cmd_handler() on `else` isn't working. Maybe someone can give me a tip how to solve it.

EDIT:

It should look like this, if there is no input(2x for example) on stdin:

```
cmd:
cmd:
cmd:
```

THIS CODE ISN'T THE REAL ONE!

regards

Comment: how do you define `no input`? based on some expiry time or empty return?

Comment: Based on empty return!

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop. I would suggest a while loop with an exit condition, perhaps set by an "exit" command.

```
int run = 1;
while (run) {
    printf("cmd: ");
    ...
    else if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
        run = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `fgets()` returns NULL, not whether command is NULL:

```
if (fgets(command, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL)
```

Then you can add an 'else' clause to handle the error condition, as you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The way you check for *empty* string is not going to work.

```
  if(command != NULL)
```

This condition will always evaluate to true as `command`, in the expression, gets converted to a pointer and is always non-null.

To check if there are any alpha-numeric characters, use `isalnum()` from `<ctype.h>` and ensure there's no whitespace characters in `command`. You seem to want to use recursion whereas a loop is probably more suited.

```
char command[LINE_MAX];
int alnum=0;

  while(1) {
    alnum=0;
    printf("cmd: ");
    fgets(command, LINE_MAX, stdin);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(command);i++)
      if(isalnum(command[i])) {
        alnum=1;
        break;
      }

    if(!alnum) continue;

    if(strcmp(command, "xyz"))
    {
      xyz();
    }
   ....
   break;
  }
```

This way, you can ensure it handles any whitespace you may input. But rest of your `strcmp(command"xyy")` will fail if user inputs `"   xyz"`. So it may suffice to check whether user simply hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
if(command[0] == '\n') continue;
```

instead of the above check using `alnum()`.